# Mining without pool where does the bitcoin/reward go if successful?

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-reward, cgminer, solo-mining

I was wondering 2 things:

How to set up `cgminer` to mine without a pool?

If if I am successful solving the block how do I claim it / send to my Bitcoin wallet?

I don't have a huge 'rig'. I know you need high hashrate… just starting out and want to know. I can't find this answer anywhere else sorry to ask.

Comment: related: [Solo mining without a pool?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41921/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `cgminer` documentation about "solo mining".  You'll need to install and set up `bitcoind` and sync the entire block chain, so see its documentation as well.

As far as payouts, note the `--btc-address` command line option to `cgminer`; that specifies the address to which the reward will be sent.

Comment: Thanks @Nate I will have a look. Also a quick one. Even with a low hash rate is it possible to solve the blockchain and receive bitcoin? Probably dreaming right? But if i was lucky i could right?

Comment: Theoretically, sure.  Practically, probably not.  Depends what your hash rate actually is.  There are innumerable calculators out there that will tell you just how "lucky" you would have to be.

Comment: @PavleStojanovic: To get a feeling for your chances of succeeding at solo-mining have a look here: [Lottery Mining?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37496/5406), [Solo mining just for luck, realistic?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16687/5406), [What are the odds of discovering a block as a solo miner?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/14346/5406)

Comment: Though keep in mind that some of those questions are several years old; with increased mining difficulty, the chances have gotten *much* worse since then.  The method for computing chances hasn't changed, but the numbers are very different

Comment: thanks guys, so I did some reading, and just for fun, not trying to profit etc etc... I think I setup cgminer to 'solo mine', I had to create a bitcoin.conf file update the username, password and ip address (127.0.0.1) then I plugged my miners in and ran this command: "cgminer -o http://localhost:8332 -u username -p password --btc-address 14Wuz9LNpNgXZoWotccwrsD3ucLmabQNaN" it didnt throw any errors but not sure I did it right ? i uploaded a screenshot here http://pasteboard.co/1QEOdW56.png

Comment: @PavleStojanovic: Appears to be working.  You'll know for sure when you actually mine a block.  Should only take about 43000 years on average.  (Yes, that's the actual number, based on your hash rate.)  Enjoy your electricity bills in the meantime.

Comment: thanks mate. yeah I know I have no chance really. but just to know how to set it up and successfully run it is what I'm after :) thanks for your time and effort to get back to me. now when I solve a block in 43000 years i'll share with you :) lol thanks again